# revalidatePath doesn't reset the form in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js

I've a form as a client component that calls a server action when submitted with

```
 <Form {...form}>
    <form
      ref={ref}
      onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    >
```

and

```
function onSubmit(data: z.infer<typeof FormSchema>) {
    startTransition(async () => {
      ref.current?.reset();
      requestImg(data).then((imageStringify) => {
```

`requestImg()` is my server action with, at the very end, before returning the actual value has `revalidatePath("/");`

Unfortunately the form doesn't reset its field.

I've also tried with `const ref = React.useRef<HTMLFormElement>(null);` as you can see from the `ref={ref}` on the form but, yet, it doesn't work

How can I reset the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to simply call `form.reset();`